Potential Textbook Typo in Calculation of Lorentz Transformation
In the 3rd edition of Goldstein's Classical Mechanics (pp. 283-284), the authors consider three inertial frames $S_{1}$, $S_{2}$, and $S_{3}$ where the Lorentz transformation from $S_{1}$ to $S_{2}$ is given by
\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{L} = \left(\begin{array}{cccc}
\gamma & -\gamma \beta & 0 & 0\\
-\gamma \beta & \gamma & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right)
\end{equation*}
and the Lorentz transformation from $S_{2}$ to $S_{3}$ is given by
\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{L}' = \left(\begin{array}{*4{>{\displaystyle}c}}
\gamma' & -\gamma' \beta'_{x'} & -\gamma' \beta'_{y'} & 0\\
-\gamma' \beta'_{x'} & 1+(\gamma'-1)\frac{{\beta'_{x'}}^{2}}{(\beta')^{2}} & (\gamma'-1)\frac{\beta'_{x'}\beta'_{y'}}{(\beta')^{2}} & 0\\
-\gamma' \beta'_{y'} & (\gamma'-1)\frac{\beta'_{x'}\beta'_{y'}}{(\beta')^{2}} & 1+(\gamma'-1)\frac{{\beta'_{y'}}^{2}}{(\beta')^{2}} & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right).
\end{equation*}
They claim that if the components of $\mathbf{\beta}'$ are so small that only at most linear terms need be considered, we can write
\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{L}'\mathbf{L} = \left(\begin{array}{cccc}
\gamma\gamma' & -\gamma\gamma'\beta & -\gamma'\beta'_{y'} & 0\\
-\gamma \beta & \gamma & 0 & 0\\
-\gamma\gamma'\beta'_{y'} & \gamma\beta\gamma'\beta'_{y'} & \gamma' & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right).
\end{equation*}
Making the approximation myself, noting that $\gamma'-1$ is of order $(\beta')^{2}$, I obtain instead
\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{L}'\mathbf{L} = \left(\begin{array}{cccc}
\gamma\gamma' & -\gamma\gamma'\beta & -\gamma'\beta'_{y'} & 0\\
-\gamma \beta & \gamma & 0 & 0\\
-\gamma\gamma'\beta'_{y'} & \gamma\beta\gamma'\beta'_{y'} & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right).
\end{equation*}
I realize that this is verging on a "check my calculations" question, which is boring and not necessarily on topic, but this is bothering me. It's not mentioned in the errata, so I don't think it's a textbook error, but I also can't find a mistake in my own work. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Is there a physically clear reason that the textbook's expression should be correct and my expression incorrect?
Edit. The only difference between the textbook's expression and mine is that in the $(3,3)$ entry the book has $\gamma'$ but I have $1$.

Did you check for errata pages?

@Qmechanic Yes I did, and the ones hosted by one of the co-authors (http://astro.physics.sc.edu/Goldstein/) don't mention it. That co-author has been dead for some time now, though, and the page hasn't been updated since 2010.

If I got it, the difference is only in the element $(3,3)$ of the product matrix. By the expressions that you provided
$$
(\mathbf L'\mathbf L)_{3,3} = \mathbf L'_{3,3}\mathbf L_{3,3} = 1+(\gamma'-1){\beta_{y'}^{'2}\over \beta^{'2}}
$$
Making the approximations, as you said
$$
{\gamma'-1\over \beta^{'2}} \approx 1
$$
So it remains $1+\beta_{y'}^{'2}$. Discarding the quadratic term, this entry should approach $1$ like your expression, not $\gamma'$.
EDIT:
I confused your answer and the book answer, I'm sorry.
Let's do a sanity check. The expression could be calculated, without approximations, for the special case of $\beta_{y'} =0$.  Your result recover the correct answer in this special case, but by no means the book answer recovers it. So you're right!

Sorry, my expression has the $1$ and the book's has the $\gamma'$. You and I seem to have the same reasoning.

Thanks for your answer! I won't accept it as correct just yet because I want to see what other people might have to say.
